# which variance is smaller , bivariate gaussian . $Var(Y1_{X<=K})$ or $Var(Y1_{X>K})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, normal-distribution, variance, bivariate-distributions

Given X,Y bivariate normal with correlation $\rho$ and $0$ means,and stddevs = $1$ , K>$0$ , which variance is smaller:

$Var(Y1_{X<=K})$ or $Var(Y1_{X>K})$ ?

context: $E(Y1_{X<=K})$ , which is equal to $-E(Y1_{X>K})$ arises in several quantitative finance applications like Stochastic Local Volatility. Intuitively it's preferable to calculate $E(Y1_{X<=K})$ because the probabilty distribution is centered on $0$ and therefore has higher mass there. but would like to confirm that variance of $E(Y1_{X<=K})$ is smaller. It potentially could depend on $\rho$ .

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Might this depend on $\rho$ ?

Comment: maybe. i dont know the answer